# Other way to transport data aside from Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This thought have been bugging me for a while but is there any other way to transport/send data from the UI to the Backend(i.e. .Net), aside from `<html><form>` and `ajax()`? I think .ajax is now the mainstream technology for this, but are there anything else?

Points of concern:

1. .ajax() by jquery which is used by plenty of plugins, is based from Javascript, so when there's some faulty code within the js file, all goes south and its hard to debug. Also, when browser have javascript disabled, I reckon this will also not work.
2. From my experience, whenever there's a problem with the data that came from the backend(web service) i.e. Exceptions, the page rendering becomes distorted and other elements fails to display.

Comment: Can you be more spesific?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. .ajax() by jquery which is used by plenty of plugins, is based from Javascript, so when there's some faulty code within the js file, all goes south and its hard to debug. Also, when browser have javascript disabled, I reckon this will also not work.

*The* fallback for everything that will not work in a no-JS-available scenario *is* HTML.

If you want me to be able to submit data even without JS activated/available – then *use* an HTML Form, that’s what they are *for*.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript are elemental keywords.

> 1. From my experience, whenever there's a problem with the data that came from the backend(web service) i.e. Exceptions, the page rendering becomes distorted and other elements fails to display.

Handling possible errors/exceptions is *your* responsibility – if you eff that up, your fault.

jQuery’s .ajax (and the related methods) provide means of handling this, f.e. the success/error callbacks. To prevent it from receiving responses that it can not handle at all (f.e. 500 Internal Server Error or the like) is your job as well.

Comment: I agree on you on all of your points. It is just really stunning that ajax is the most prevalent method on how to accomplish this.I basically work on MVC + .net framework as backend and we are currently migrating some legacy ASPX component to MVC as well. I hope to hear some more inputs regarding this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about jquery, then what comes in mind is `.ajax()` or `.post()`